# Display div at top of page?

Tags: css, html, position, positioning

Basically, the current setup has space between the top of the page and the #header div. I want to remove that space. Tried searching, came up with adding

```
position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
```

to the `#header` div, it works (positions it at the top without space) but the rest of my divs loose all their structure. How to position it at the very top and preserve the current layout of the rest of the divs?

I am also using an image underneath the divs as a background. Using this code.

```
body
{
background-image:url('../imagez/bestone1400.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top, center;background-size:100%; 2000px;
}
```

Thanks in advanced.

```
#container
{
width:100%;
}

#header
{
background-color:#FFA500;
height:400px;
}

#leftcolumn
{
background-color:#FFD700;
height:200px;
width:10%;
float:left;
}

#content
{
background-color:#EEEEEE;
height:200px;
width:80%;
float:left;
}

#rightcolumn
{
background-color:#FFD700;
height:200px;
width:10%;
float:right;
}

#footer
{
background-color:#FFA500;
clear:both;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely `padding` or `margin` on html or body.  Try something like:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

There may also be padding or magins on divs or other elements, so a universal selector might work:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

But it is generally good practice to implement a css reset, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/omargourari/5212116), which may be the best solution.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. That removed the padding on the sides but not at the top (the space is still there). I am using an image as a background underneath the divs with this code body
{
background-image:url('image1.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top, center;background-size:100%; 2000px;} could this be affecting it?

Comment: What's the '2000px' at the end there?

Comment: Yes! The universal selector seems to have worked! Thank you very much, I have been trying to figure this out for so long. :D Thank you. I will also fix up my code to make it look nicer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the Default browser padding, margin and border, use:

```
/*reset default browser settings */
html, body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
}
```